# Insert Dataset Table records to SQLite table - in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678901/insert-data-in-sqlite-using-dataset-in-c-sharp) in C (Or C# maybe), but I don't really understand C. I'm a vb guy (and new to .net).  Can anyone give me a hand in converting this to vb?

The concept appears to be exactly what I need:
  I've got an Excel worksheet loaded to a dataset table.
  I have an identical table in the SQLite db (column for column).
  I want to save the imported Worksheet data in the dataset table to the empty SQLite table.

Here is the code from the link:

```
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection; 
void createDbAndTable()
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;");
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    string sql = "create table myValues (name varchar(20), highScore int)";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

void fillTable(DataSet ds)
{
    var dt = ds.Tables[0];

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        var name = dr["name"].ToString();
        var score = Convert.ToInt32(dr["value"].ToString());
        string sql = "insert into myValues (name, highScore) values ( '" + name + "'," + score + ")";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have accomplished the 3 tasks you listed so all you need is the Insert. Yes? BTW, it is C# not C. Big difference. Here is a great code converter. http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Yes!  Thanks again Mary!